# Logging into macos from linux and exporting display

Tags: ssh, macos-sierra, x11-forwarding

I'm running macos sierra and for some reason I can't get the following to work on sierra.

I want to ssh in to my macos machine from a linux desktop, export my display back, and run either chrome or safari on my linux display.

I have xquartz installed and sshd_config set up correctly. I successfully get a DISPLAY variable set which proves xauth is working, however, when I launch Chrome or Safari it is displayed on the macos desktop.

I've had this working on every version of macos until sierra.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have xquartz installed for this direction of X forwarding. What you need however are applications that use the X protocol for displaying themselves. Your Mac's Chrome or Safari do not use it.

Mac does not use X server, and has its own API for dealing with windows and rendering on screen. Most applications you have installed (including Chrome and Safari) are using this API and know nothing about X11 and will ignore the DISPLAY variable. Only some special applications (typically those ported from Linux) use X11 on Mac and those render using xqartz (for example `xterm` or `inkscape`). Those are the only applications for which you can use X forwarding from Mac to Linux.

I doubt there is a working build of Chrome/Chromium for Mac that uses X11 and I am certain there is not one of Safari. I would recommend using VNC to get remote desktop from Mac to Linux.